# Progress bar cant reset after submitting form using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Hi Good afternoon please help me i have a problem in my progress bar. my progress bar wont reset after submitting the form and i used
ajax for inserting data i want to reset my progress bar after
triggering the submit button. i used the progress bar for password.here is my code in progress bar:
    my submit button name: "insert-data

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $.fn.bootstrapPasswordMeter = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            minPasswordLength: 1,
            level0ClassName: 'progress-bar-danger',
            level0Description: 'Weak',
            level1ClassName: 'progress-bar-warning',
            level1Description: 'Poor',
            level2ClassName: 'progress-bar-info',
            level2Description: 'Good',
            level3ClassName: 'progress-bar-Primary',
            level3Description: 'Strong',
            level4ClassName: 'progress-bar-success',
            level4Description: 'Very strong',
            parentContainerClass: '.form-group'
        }, options || {});

        $(this).on("keyup", function() {
            var progressBar = $(this).closest(settings.parentContainerClass).find('.progress-bar');
            var progressBarWidth = 0;
            var progressBarDescription = '';
            if ($(this).val().length >= settings.minPasswordLength) {
                var zxcvbnObj = zxcvbn($(this).val());
                progressBar.removeClass(settings.level0ClassName)
                    .removeClass(settings.level1ClassName)
                    .removeClass(settings.level2ClassName)
                    .removeClass(settings.level3ClassName)
                    .removeClass(settings.level4ClassName)
                switch (zxcvbnObj.score) {
                    case 0:
                        progressBarWidth = 0;
                        progressBar.addClass(settings.level0ClassName);
                        progressBarDescription = settings.level0Description;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        progressBarWidth = 25;
                        progressBar.addClass(settings.level1ClassName);
                        progressBarDescription = settings.level1Description;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        progressBarWidth = 50;
                        progressBar.addClass(settings.level2ClassName);
                        progressBarDescription = settings.level2Description;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        progressBarWidth = 75;
                        progressBar.addClass(settings.level3ClassName);
                        progressBarDescription = settings.level3Description;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        progressBarWidth = 100;
                        progressBar.addClass(settings.level4ClassName);
                        progressBarDescription = settings.level4Description;
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                progressBarWidth = 0;
                progressBarDescription = '';
            }
            progressBar.css('width', progressBarWidth + '%');
            progressBar.text(progressBarDescription);
        });
    };
    $('#Password').bootstrapPasswordMeter({
        minPasswordLength: 3
    });
    });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors occurs in this condition:

```
$(this).val().length >= settings.minPasswordLength
```

But without a working snippet is difficult to say if it is failing the left or the right side of the condition. It seems it is always TRUE while you need it to be FALSE at certain point.

Comment: can you explain it in easier way sir. i dont get it

Comment: $(this).val().length has a value greater than settings.minPasswordLength. Try to colsole.log() their values before the if condition and track the problem.